# Removing an Element from a repository with Spring and Html

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to Remove a topic from CrudRepository, but the checkboxes I am trying to create don't show up.
I have an Add Method which works just fine, but the remove doesn't.

HTML: **hello.html** 
for the navigation and head fragments

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head th:fragment="head">
    <title> Lunch Planner Beta </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>

</head>
<body>
<h1 th:inline="text">Hello  [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]!</h1>

<nav th:fragment="navigation">
    <a href="/api/topics">List</a> |
    <a href="/addTopic">Add</a> |
    <a th:href="/removeTopic">Remove</a>
</nav>


<form th:action="@{/home}" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Home"/>
</form>

<br/>

<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign OUT"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The part of **TopicController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/remove", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
@Transactional
public ModelAndView deleteTopic(Long id, HttpServletResponse response, Errors errors){
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
    model.addObject("topic",topicService.getTopic(id));
    topicService.deleteTopic(id);

    return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```

HTML: **removeTopic.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org/">
<head th:replace="hello :: head">
</head>

<body class="container">

<nav th:replace="hello :: navigation"></nav>

<form th:action="@{/api/remove}" th:object="${topic}" method="post">
    <div th:each="topic: ${topic}" class="checkbox">
        <input type="radio" name="id" th:value="${topics.id}" th:id="${topics.id}"/>
        <label th:for="${topics.id}" th:text="${topics.category}"></label>
        <br/>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Remove Topic"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is what is happeneing:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the loop, you are using the same object to iterate itself

```
th:each="topic: ${topic}"
```

You should have something similar to this

```
<div th:each="item: ${topics}" class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="id" th:value="${item.id}" th:id="${item.id}"/>
    <label th:for="${item.id}" th:text="${item.category}"></label>
    <br/> <!-- Do not use this tag to add vertical space, use css classes-->
</div>
```

Comment: should I then change the attributeName in the controller?

Comment: in the controller you are sending a list of topics, then in your controller should have the name "topics" and then in the html use the code i added

Comment: The topics still don't appear as checkboxes on the remove page

Comment: could do you verify that the list "topics" is not empty?

Comment: for sure, I am always editing topics before going to the remove page

Comment: oks, check my latest response, I saw you already have other object called topic, so the iteration over topics list must to be with another name, i used "item", try this code and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154355/discussion-between-cralfaro-and-panayot-zhaltov).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2757561/cralfaro we were able to fix the connection between the controller and the removeTopic.html

The problem was is the **hello.html** at the

```
<a th:href="/removeTopic">Remove</a>
```

and **this** is how it should be:

```
<a th:href="@{/api/removeTopic}">Remove</a>
```